# Configure traps in snmpd.conf with TLS certificates in net-snmp

Tags: ssl, certificate, tls1.2, net-snmp, snmp-trap

How to configure the net-snmp agent (snmpd.conf) to send traps using TLS and certificates?

Will it reuse the server snmp server cert and use it as a client cert towards the trapd server?
Can you configure a cert per trapsink target?

An example snmpd.conf would help.
An answer to look at the net-snmp snmpd.conf man page would not help. Already did...
Also looked here: http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_DTLS#Configuring_Servers

Comment: Concerns configuring a service, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trapsess` token actually follows the same conventions in the `snmpcmd` manual page, which includes TLS/DTLS options.  (In fact, internally, it uses the same argument parsing code).

So...  you actually can replace "snmpget" inall the `snmpget` examples from the tutorial page you quoted with an appropriate `trapsess` directive and put it in your snmpd.conf file.  EG, You can use the "-T our_identity=foo" and "-T their_identity=snmptrapd" types of tokens in the `trapsess` line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hard to read that from the tutorial and docs.